# How to overwrite default onKeyDown

Tags: reactjs

Can we change the default values of keys on the keyboard in React JS? I want it to behave like       enter when I press Tab. I got an error doing this

```js
const handleKeyDown = (e:KeyboardEvent\<HTMLInputElement\>) =\> {
    if (e.code === 'Tab') {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.code === "Enter" //This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"Tab"' and '"Enter"' have no overlap.
    }
};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback. How can we help you with a error if you don't share the error

Comment: Please share the error as mentioned above. Also, `e.code === "Enter"` wouldn't work as I believe it is a read-only property. Just do the action you would do if a user presses Enter inside that if, setting the code property wouldn't help.

Comment: I got this: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"Tab"' and '"Enter"' have no overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `KeyboardEvent` when the Tab is pressed and then dispatch the event.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

```
  const onKeydown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    const {target, key} = event
    if (key == "Tab") {
      event.preventDefault(); // You need to prevent tab event. 
      
      const keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
        key: "Enter",
        bubbles: true,
      });
      target?.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
    }

    if (key === "Enter") {
      console.log("Enter");  // Do what you want to do here.
    }
  };
```

#### Try this

*This code logs Enter whenever either **Tab** or **Enter** is pressed.*

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")

input.onkeydown = (event) => {
  if (event.key == "Tab") {
    event.preventDefault()
    const keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      key: 'Enter',
      bubbles: true
    });
    event.target.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
  }

  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    console.log("Enter")
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```